# cups-pdf - not printing PDF to Pi

Tags: raspbian, cups

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi as a virtual pdf printer.

I ran `sudo apt-get install printer-driver-cups-pdf` and logged into `192.168.1.225:631` which is the static IP of my Pi. Afterwards I created a virtual printer with the name `pdf_wydruk`. (I check in `Share printer` during the create process). I opened a random picture and clicked print, chose `pdf-wydruk` to use and nothing.

I cannot find this file anywhere! I created `/home/pi/PDF` because I read this is the default path. I checked another default folder `/var/spool/cups-pds/ANONYMOUS`. I found `0.pdf` with the actual time of editing but that file is empty - I don't have any picture or text from my desktop.

The version of Raspbian I am using is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/log/cups $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Logs for `cups`:

`/var/log/cups/cups-pdf-pdf_wydruk_log`

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/log/cups $ sudo cat cups-pdf-pdf_wydruk_log 
Tue Nov  9 14:55:40 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 14:55:41 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:08:00 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:08:00 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:20:50 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:20:50 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:21:33 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:21:33 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:22:02 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:22:02 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:25:58 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:25:59 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:31:52 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:31:52 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:32:56 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:32:56 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:36:35 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:36:35 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:46:41 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:46:41 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 15:52:16 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 15:52:16 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 16:13:08 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 16:13:08 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 16:29:22 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 16:29:22 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 16:48:14 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 16:48:14 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 16:48:23 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 16:48:23 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
Tue Nov  9 16:49:10 2021  [STATUS] ***Experimental Option: DecodeHexStrings
Tue Nov  9 16:49:11 2021  [STATUS] PDF creation successfully finished for nobody
```

`/var/log/cups/access_log`

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/log/cups $ cat access_log
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:14:55:05 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:14:55:05 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:14:55:37 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 2499 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:35 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 - -
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:35 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 88 CUPS-Get-Devices successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:35 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:35 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 - -
192.168.1.116 - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:05:37 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 - -
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:37 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 88 CUPS-Get-Devices successful-ok
localhost - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:05:37 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2161 CUPS-Get-Devices -
192.168.1.116 - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:05:37 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3639 - -
192.168.1.116 - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:05:50 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 - -
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:50 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 88 CUPS-Get-Devices successful-ok
localhost - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:05:50 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2161 CUPS-Get-Devices -
192.168.1.116 - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:05:50 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3639 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:56 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 113 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:56 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 3090 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:58 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 225 - -
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:58 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 7469 CUPS-Get-PPDs -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:05:58 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 6021 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:06:07 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 1818 - -
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:06:07 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 292 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:06:07 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 401 1818 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:06:07 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 1818 - -
192.168.1.116 - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:06:07 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 1818 - -
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:06:07 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 292 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:06:07 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 292 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:06:07 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 3776 - -
192.168.1.116 - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:06:36 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 141 - -
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:06:36 +0100] "PUT /admin/conf/cupsd.conf HTTP/1.1" 401 0 - -
localhost - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:06:36 +0100] "PUT /admin/conf/cupsd.conf HTTP/1.1" 201 4827 - -
192.168.1.116 - pi [09/Nov/2021:15:06:36 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 4542 - -
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:06:54 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:06:54 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:07:56 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 39730 Print-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:08:06 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2021:15:08:06 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:08:06 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:08:14 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:08:14 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:19:19 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2021:15:19:19 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:19:19 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:19:27 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:19:27 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:20:47 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 39730 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:21:30 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 39730 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:21:59 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 39730 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:25:30 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 90 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:25:30 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4702 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:25:46 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 141 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:25:46 +0100] "POST /admin HTTP/1.1" 200 4753 - -
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:25:56 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 2500 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:31:49 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 2500 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:32:54 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 431788 Print-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:34:23 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2021:15:34:23 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:34:23 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:34:30 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:34:30 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:36:33 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 431788 Print-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:45:09 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2021:15:45:09 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:45:09 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:45:16 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:15:45:16 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:46:39 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 431788 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:15:52:14 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 380526 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:16:13:06 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 133421 Print-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:16:27:40 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2021:16:27:40 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:16:27:40 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:16:27:48 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:16:27:48 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2021:16:27:58 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 24354 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2021:16:27:58 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 24354 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2021:16:27:58 +0100] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 204 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer client-error-bad-request
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:16:29:20 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 380526 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:16:48:12 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 380526 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:16:48:21 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 380526 Print-Job successful-ok
192.168.1.116 - - [09/Nov/2021:16:49:08 +0100] "POST /printers/pdf_wydruk HTTP/1.1" 200 93213 Print-Job successful-ok
```

Maybe somebody has an idea as to what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i installed at the fresh image of raspberry pi and that works. Probably i had have something bad set in privillege.

1. installed only cups for first
   `sudo apt install cups`
2. i check my ip at ethernet/wifi via `ifconfig`
3. I open configuration file for cups

   sudo vim /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

i find them line
`Listen localhost:631` and change them to `Port 631`

next - i added `Allow @local` in three places - result below

```
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @local
</Location>

# Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @local
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @local
</Location>
```

4. I restarted services - `sudo service cups restart`
   now i should access at my desktop to raspberry cups by url `192.168.1.225:631` ( i get that ip from `ifconfig` command )
5. i added usermod for pi

   sudo usermod -a -G lpadmin pi
6. I installed cups-pdf -- now they have new name 'printer-driver-cups-pdf`

   sudo apt-get install printer-driver-cups-pdf
7. I added printer generic --> generic-cups-pdf like guy at that spanish movie

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHQuCkrqTS4
administration -> add printer -> cups-pdf -> i called printer-pdf polish `pdf-wydruk`

8)
i created folder at raspberry pi /home/pi/PDF

At ip_raspberry_pi:631 in browser click `Printers` -> `Maintenance` --> Print test page --- and ... i should have test pdf file at my raspberry `/home/pi/PDF` if you don't find - check `/var/spool/cups-pdf` folder and should be folder `pi` or `ANONYMOUS` and looking for that pdf file.

9. In my project i have wanted share that file for other computer in network so i install samba

`sudo apt install samba`
i said `no` to window with ask, because i don't need settings `WINS` with `DHCP` - I set static ip for raspberry pi

I created folder `/samba/wydruki`

```
sudo mkdir -p /samba/wydruki
sudo chmod -R 777 /samba/wydruki
sudo chmod -R nobody.nogroup /samba/wydruki
sudo chmod -R 777 /samba
```

10. I changed to settings file using `sudo vim /etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
[Publiczny]
    path = /samba/wydruki
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create_mask = 777
```

11. I restarted services samba

```
    sudo service smbd restart
    sudo service nmbd restart
```

12. I changed file conf `cups-pdf`

```
    sudo vim /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf
```

and i comment two old line and added new with path to `/samba/wydruki`

```
##  CUPS-PDF output directory 
##  special qualifiers: 
##     ${HOME} will be expanded to the user's home directory
##     ${USER} will be expanded to the user name
##  in case it is an NFS export make sure it is exported without
##  root_squash!
##  on Ubuntu, the cupsd AppArmor profile needs to be updated
##  to match the output path as per instructions in LP:147551
### Default: /var/spool/cups-pdf/${USER}

#Out ${HOME}/PDF
Out /samba/wydruki

### Key: AnonDirName (config)
##  ABSOLUTE path for anonymously created PDF files
##  if anonymous access is disabled this setting has no effect
### Default: /var/spool/cups-pdf/ANONYMOUS

#AnonDirName /var/spool/cups-pdf/ANONYMOUS
AnonDirName /samba/wydruki
```